# How to find common values in X files that do not occur in Y files

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have 90 txt files with one column only. I want to find words occurring in files 1-30 but not in files 31-90.

The files are named 1.txt, 2.txt, and so on.

Is there a quick way to do this with awk, python or bash?

Comment: That may depend on how the files are named. Apparently, they do have an ordering, so you should use that. We can't guess that for you.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner using `bash`, and shell utilities `sort` and `comm`:

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort {1..30}.txt) <(sort {31..90}.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might harness `python`'s `set` arithmetic for this task as follows

```
def file_to_set(fname):
    with open("unodostres.txt","r") as f:
        return set(i.strip() for i in f)
words = file_to_set("1.txt")
for i in range(2,31):
    words = words.intersection(str(i)+".txt")
for i in range(31,91):
    words = words.difference(str(i)+".txt")
print(words)
```

Explanation: `file_to_set` read file, jettison leading and trailing whitespaces from line and convert it into set. `words` is created by converting `1.txt`, then for `2.txt` to `30.txt` (`range` is inclusive-exclusive) I find common words between words so far and from current file and store it in `words`, then for `31.txt` to `90.txt` I remove from `words` all elements which are present in said files. Finally I `print` words.